# Assigning Values to multi dimensional Eigen matrix in c++?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3

I have an Eigen matrix with a vector as the scalar type, defined as the following

```
Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::VectorXd, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> res = Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::VectorXd, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>::
        Constant(10,
            10,
            Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(3));
```

I can access and assign values as the following

```
res(0,0)(0) = 1;
```

I am trying to assign a matrix to each third index as the following

```
res(all_rows,all_cols)(0) = matrix
```

The following is my code

```
int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::VectorXd, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> res = Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::VectorXd, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>::
        Constant(10,
            10,
            Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(3));

    Eigen::MatrixXf x = Eigen::MatrixXf::Ones(10, 1)*2;
    Eigen::MatrixXf y = Eigen::MatrixXf::Ones(10, 1);
    Eigen::MatrixXf product = Eigen::MatrixXf::Zero(10, 10);
    MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    res(0, 0)(0) = 1;
    m(0, 0) = 3;
    m(1, 0) = 2.5;

    m(0, 1) = -1;
    m(1, 1) = m(1, 0) + m(0, 1);
    product = x*y.transpose();
    res.block(0,0,10,10)(0) = x*y.transpose();
}
```

But when I try to compile the code, This line is giving the error

```
res.block(0,0,10,10)(0) = x*y.transpose();
```

I am getting the following following error.

```
Error   C2338   THIS_COEFFICIENT_ACCESSOR_TAKING_ONE_ACCESS_IS_ONLY_FOR_EXPRESSIONS_ALLOWING_LINEAR_ACCESS
```

Is there a way to overcome this, or should I change my approach?

Comment: You are assigning the outer product x*y^T matrix to the first element of the 10x10 block which is an Eigen::VectorXd. Looks like you are looking for tensor types.

Comment: You have to define several scalar operations, if you use Eigen::VectorXd as scalar. A better option is either using a Eigen::Tensor of rank 3, or a flattened matrix of size (3, width*height) with usual scalar (double in your case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use `Eigen::VectorXd` as the scalar type. So you should make sure you have extended `Eigen::NumTraits` as explained in https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html

It looks like you are trying to recreate a multi-channel array or image. So you won't gain a lot by the above method. A better idea is to use either a `Eigen::Tensor` of rank 3, or a flattened matrix of size (3, width*height). Then you get all the Eigen benefits (vectorized scalar operations, no weird access pattern like (row, col)(channel), etc )

```
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> rgb_image(height, width, 3);
Eigen::MatrixXd rgb_image(3, width*height); // Each column is a pixel color
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions